# How to use callbacks in keras subclassed model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, subclass

I instantiate keras subclassed model, as [tensorflow guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras),

To be able to use `.fit` to my model class, I need to create `compute_output_shape` . Nevertheless, using callbacks for fitted model throw `NotImplementedError`.

So, what can I do to use callbacks in keras subclassed model, such as tensorboard, checkpoints, etc ?

Comment: have you added callbacks argument in model.compile step?

Comment: @A.Chandu, no, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Have you got an answer? I guess the [ModelCheckpoint](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint) callback can be used if we use the `save_weights_only=True`, as suggested by [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/keras/saving_and_serializing#saving_subclassed_models)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```py
model = SubclassModel()
# Callbacks you can define
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='model')
# Add callbacks to fit parameter
model.fit(data, labels, batch_size=100, epochs=5, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```